# How to delete an object with a windows.confirm?

Tags: javascript, django

I have a template that lists all the activities of a client. In this template, I have a button to delete any activity I choose. This button has a confirmation to delete through a windows.confirm. But it's not working the way you expect. Sometimes the button works, sometimes it doesn't.

```
{% for servico in object_list %}                   
     {{ servico.refferring_funcionario }}
     {{ servico.get_lista_servico_display }}
     {{ servico.data_servico }}
     R$ {{ servico.valor_servico }}
     <a href="{% url 'servico:editar-servico' servico.id %}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Edit</a>
     <a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return myFunction()">Delete</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Js

```
<script>
   function myFunction() {
        if (window.confirm("Você tem certeza que deseja excluir ?")) {                                      
            window.location.href="{% url 'servico:excluir-servico' servico.id %}";
        }
   }
```

Comment: Does it show any error on the console? When does it not work?

Comment: No, it just doesn't work. This script is inside the for to get the servico.id. Is that it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is the problem, but to start solving the problem I would set the value of **href** to **#**

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return myFunction()">Delete</a>
```